# how to find a function f(n) (continuous on R) such that $(-1)^{f(n)}$ is positive when $n=1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10....$, and <0 for other natural number?

Tags: calculus

Further more, can we have a general way to find $f(n)$ which is negative whenever we design?
(note: we just take $n$ as natural number)

I think some function with $\sin$, $\cos$ will satisfy this.

Comment: what is the image of $f$ ? $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @Falcon Yes thanks

Comment: the function $(-1)^{f(x)}$ is not well define when $f(x) \in \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb N$.

Comment: emm..That's a problem. What about let f(x)$\in$N when $n\in N$

Answer (score 1):

To put it another way: you want continuous $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(n)$ is an even integer for $n=1,2,5,6,9,10,\ldots$ and an odd integer for $n=3,4,7,8,11,12,\ldots$

Looking at the graph of this, it is clear than a $\cos$ function will do the trick, with maxima at $x=1.5,5.5,9.5,\ldots$ Can you see how to do this?